# Do GitHub pages support memcachier?

Tags: memcached, octopress, github-pages

On the [memcachier faq](https://www.memcachier.com/faq) page I see that the supported platform providers are Heroku, AppFog, AWS and a few others, but GitHub Pages is not mentioned explicitly. Furthermore, they say:

> What does the memcachier gem do?
>
> The memcachier gem is relevant for customers in Heroku, AppFog, and cloudControl. It copies the MEMCACHIER* environment variables to MEMCACHE*, which is where most client libraries expect to find SASL credentials.

So, in other words, the question is: does it make sense to use the `memcachier` and `dalli` gems on my Octopress blog, hosted on GitHub Pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub pages runs a small subset of plugins / gems. `memcachier` and `dalli` gems are not on the list